If existing top players never play someone, how to predict who would win if they play?
If a new strong player never gets the chance to play against existing top players, how can people best predict the win-rate or likelihood of outcomes if they hypothetically play? One possible way is to use their ratings, if they have played games against a common pool of other strong players, but merely comparing ratings computed from games with others doesn't take into account their play styles, preparations and psychological factors. For example, established top players may have many games against top opponents that anyone can study, but the other player might not have that kind of experience of playing top opponents. On the other hand, the new player may be less worried about winning/losing than established players.
(An extreme but not entirely impossible scenario inspired by recent events. Not the same as questions about comparing against players from a different era/before ratings existed, in part because the players involved are contemporary and do keep playing games, just not against each other.)

All rating systems depends on players having recently played many other players of their ability.  Once you get to the top handful of players this is no longer possible unless they have all played each other.
